# Showing a UIAlertController when there is a NSConstraintConflict

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm inserting data into my CoreData stack (which has only one entity with a few attributes). In Xcode, I've set the attribute "**patientID**" to be a unique constraint.
When attempting to add a new entry, this does as expected and throws an error in Xcode's console (`NSConstraintConflict`). However, in-app nothing is shown.

**How would I go about adding a UIAlertController to state that this is a duplicate entry?**

My current function for saving to CoreData is as follows:

```
func save(newID: String, newDOB: String, newAge: String, newGender: String, newHeight: String, newWeight: String, newRace: String, newADLS: String) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    // 1
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    // 2
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Patient", in: managedContext)!

    let person = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)

    // 3
    person.setValue(newID, forKeyPath: "patientID")
    person.setValue(newDOB, forKey: "dob")
    person.setValue(newAge, forKey: "age")
    person.setValue(newGender, forKey: "gender")
    person.setValue(newHeight, forKey: "height")
    person.setValue(newWeight, forKey: "weight")
    person.setValue(newRace, forKey: "race")
    person.setValue(newADLS, forKey: "adls")

    // 4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        //No need for this - this occurs appends during viewWillAppear
        //ids.append(person)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch all records before every insert and verify that the new **patientID** doesn't exist before the insert and if exists show the alert

after you fetch the array

```
if fetchedArray.map{$0.patientID}.contains(newID) {
   // show alert here as id exists
   return
}
// proceed in saving the new record
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about doing this? I'm pretty much completely new to CoreData (and only a newbie at Swift in general). I know how to make a `NSFetchRequest` with a predicate, but no idea how I'd then compare that to what's been inputted by the user/show the alert etc.